# Apply a background color to app using angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

If I am changing the colour of my toolbar to primary or accent, the colour is changing. But I want to apply a background colour as well. Where do I make the changes necessary?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What did you tried ?

Comment: @RadouaneROUFID This is my theme.scss `@import '~@angular/material/_theming';
@include mat-core();
$app-root-primary: mat-palette($mat-red);
$app-root-accent:  mat-palette($mat-light-green, 500, 900, A700);
$app-root-warn:    mat-palette($mat-deep-orange);
$app-root-background:  mat-palette($mat-grey);

$app-root-theme: mat-light-theme($app-root-primary, $app-root-accent, $app-root-warn);

@include angular-material-theme($app-root-theme);`

Comment: @Samriddha by background color what do you mean ? of the body

Comment: @RahulSingh Yes.

Comment: @Samriddha i guess then you need to add the style in the global styles.css as
`body{background-color:asyourcolor`} this might work

Comment: @RahulSingh Yes it is working now with what you said. I thought the theme was where all the colour changes had to be made. Thank you for your help. :)